# How to decode orca.so api response

Tags: base64, decode, encode, web3js

I'm building my arbitrage bot with orca.so, when I try to fetch the price via their api this is the response:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "context": {
            "apiVersion": "1.14.17",
            "slot": 197346911
        },
        "value": {
            "data": [
                "DADQr+uGFNp/GaugLUDxjGklhfZQIN/O09Xl+anAxOFowQw6x63HLj9fsqaHKhx7g1G0uMOlkMFIUUE/4Y2EZgEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
                "base64"
            ],
            "executable": false,
            "lamports": 2039280,
            "owner": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
            "rentEpoch": 0
        }
    },
    "id": "32ad67cb-0da5-4df4-90fa-320ff15b84fb"
}
```

How to decode the field data? I tried to use base64 decode but it returned trash data.

I want to know how to decode orca.so api response